# automatic cast of anonymous record array type to the array type of a named composite type in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, array, record

From [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-expressions.html), it is possible to cast an anonymous record type to a named composite type at a function call site. Quoting the example there:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(f1 int, f2 float, f3 text);
CREATE FUNCTION getf1(mytable) RETURNS int AS 'SELECT $1.f1' LANGUAGE SQL;

-- No cast needed since only one getf1() exists
SELECT getf1(ROW(1,2.5,'this is a test'));
```

However, the implicit cast of record type does not seem to work for an array of anonymous records. If I slightly change the above example to work on an an array function taking `getf1a(mytable[])` as below, I get an error:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getf1a(mytable[]) RETURNS int AS 'SELECT $1[0].f1' LANGUAGE SQL;

SELECT getf1a(ARRAY[ROW(1,2.5,'this is a test')]);
```

The error says:

```
=> ERROR:  function getf1a(record[]) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT getf1a(ARRAY[ROW(1,2.5,'this is a test')]);
```

The anonymous and named array record types are compatible and there is no ambiguity. It would be nice if the cast is implicit. My question is:

Is there a way to make the implicit cast work for array record types too?

(This is with PostgreSQL 12.x)

Comment: I don't think an automatic cast will be possible. You will have to cast the array manually: `ARRAY[ROW(1,2.5,'this is a test')]::mytable[]`